# How to Use Core Data Models with In-Memory Store Type Using Prepopulated SQLite File?

Tags: unit-testing, core-data

I am following an outdated [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated) from the Ray Wenderlich team that walks through the repopulation of a `Core Data`-backed application by using a Command Line Tool application.

I have successfully prepopulated the intended entities, verified by performing an `NSFetchRequest`.

Now, I want to use the same prepopulated data in my unit tests to verify that my interactions with `CoreData` are happening correctly. I tried setting up my mocked `CoreDataStack` subclass to use an in-memory store, but when I attempt to verify that I have the prepopulated data for use in my unit tests, I am getting a `count` of `0`.

The class responsible for interacting with `CoreData` in my application's target, named `CoreDataStack`, follows:

```swift
/// The object that is responsible for managing interactions with Core Data.
internal class CoreDataStack {

    // MARK: - Properties

    /// The name of the `NSManagedObjectModel` object used for storing information with Core Data.
    private let modelName: String

    /// The `NSManagedObjectContext` object that is associated with the main queue.
    internal lazy var mainContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        return self.storeContainer.viewContext
    }()

    /// The `NSPersistentContainer` object that encapsulates the application's Core Data stack.
    internal lazy var storeContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: self.modelName)
        let directory = NSPersistentContainer.defaultDirectoryURL()
        let storeURL = directory.appendingPathComponent("\(self.modelName).sqlite")
        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: (storeURL.path)) {
            guard let populatedURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: self.modelName, withExtension: "sqlite") else {
                fatalError("Invalid populated .sqlite file URL")
            }
            do {
                try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: populatedURL, to: storeURL)
            } catch {
                fatalError("Error: \(error)")
            }
        }
        let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()
        description.url = storeURL
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Error: \(error)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    // MARK: - Initialization

    /// Returns an instance of `CoreDataStack`.
    /// - parameter modelName: The name of the `NSManagedObjectModel` object used for storing information with Core Data.
    internal init(modelName: String) {
        self.modelName = modelName
    }

    /// Attempts to save items to Core Data by committing changes to `NSManagedObject`s in a `NSManagedObjectContext`.
    /// - parameter context: The `NSManagedObjectContext` of which changes should be committed.
    internal func saveContext(_ context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        context.perform {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch let error as NSError {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The subclass of `CoreDataStack`, `MockCoreDataStack`, used for testing follows:

```swift
internal class MockCoreDataStack: CoreDataStack {

    // MARK: - Initialization

    convenience init() {
        self.init(modelName: "Currency")
    }

    override init(modelName: String) {
        super.init(modelName: modelName)
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: modelName)
        let directory = NSPersistentContainer.defaultDirectoryURL()
        let storeURL = directory.appendingPathComponent("\(modelName).sqlite")
        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: (storeURL.path)) {
            guard let populatedURL = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).url(forResource: modelName, withExtension: "sqlite") else {
                fatalError("Invalid populated .sqlite file URL")
            }
            do {
                try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: populatedURL, to: storeURL)
            } catch {
                fatalError("Error: \(error)")
            }
        }
        let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()
        description.url = storeURL
        description.type = NSInMemoryStoreType
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]
        container.loadPersistentStores { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }
        self.storeContainer = container
    }
}
```

The resulting `count` of my fetch request is `0` in my unit tests target. I expect to return a `count` consisting of the number of prepopulated objects, just as I get when I return the `count` in my application's target.

What am I doing incorrectly that is causing me to not return the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

The in memory store doesn't use the store URL. It just creates an empty store in memory.

As an alternative to the in memory store, you could possibly create a parent `NSManagedObjectContext` between the persistent store and the contexts you actually use. (I'm not sure how that would play with `NSPersistentContainer`, however.)

Then you can just `rollback()` the parent context when you want to reset back to your initial state.